# Make liquibase execute sql file in gradle task

Tags: mysql, gradle, liquibase

So what I have is:

1. MySQL DB running in docker container
2. SQL file with sql statements that need to be executed on mentioned
   mysql db when developer executes gradle task.

Currently I can import it manually with:

`docker exec -i <mysql-container-name> mysql -u<username> -p<password>  < file.sql`

And i know I can create docker exec task for this but as I see using `liquibase` for this job would be better for a lot of reasons, but I have zero experience with it and I hope someone can tell me how to configure `liquibase` and use it in this case.

Answer (score 0):

When you have a mysql running in a docker container, you connect to it using localhost. For example: `url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:<port>/<dbname>`

You can read more about it on:

1. https://docs.liquibase.com/workflows/database-setup-tutorials/mysql.html
2. https://docs.liquibase.com/tools-integrations/springboot/springboot.html